# What is the difference between "semantics" and an interpretation in a model?

Tags: category-theory, model-theory, type-theory

nLab frequently says things like "Type theory XYZ has a semantics in flavored categories." Why isn't it just saying that "the theory of *this* kind of category are a model of *that* kind of type theory?"

Comment: Because it is breifer?

Comment: So, just double checking, but a semantics of a theory is not a special structure that's different from a model of a theory? They're the same, one is just more convenient?

Comment: It seems to me that people use semantics to refer to a particular type of structure that can be used to build models for a given logic. For instance, one talks of possible world semantics, which is a framework for constructing models for modal logics.

Comment: @Nagase I'd love to know more! In particular, can we "write down" what exactly what possible world semantics is? Is it a function from something to models of modal logic?

Comment: @user52969, I'm still curious...have you found anything since so far?

Comment: My understanding is the same as that of the first comment, namely that they do mean the same thing (as you originally guessed), just that one is a briefer way of saying it. Generally people who say such things appear to be assuming that the reader is already familiar with notions of formal semantics and thus understands that they mean the same thing, in which case brevity wins out over explicitness.

Comment: 6 years later and I have logged back into stack exchange... I think Graham Kemp, Nagase, and Chill2Macht are correct. I asked this question when I was still obsessed with being rigorous over actually learning math, which I now realize are two related but distinct activities.